# DNS bind & mail server - received by unknown

Tags: email, bind, smtp-headers

I have a web server that talks to a mail server when sending an email. Now I'm hosting my own DNS, however, since then I see that one of the email headers says:

`Received: from webserver.domain.com (unknown [192.168.0.1])`

where `webserver.domain.com` has the IP `192.168.0.100` and the router where is connected has `192.168.0.1`, before I used to see the hostname of 192.168.0.1 (router.domain.com)

In the `192.168.0.rev` zone I have:
`1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR router.domain.com.`

and `domain.com.db` has:
`router                      IN      A       192.168.0.1`

`/etc/resolv.conf` on the web/mail server:

```
domain domain.com
search domain.com
nameserver 192.168.0.101
nameserver ISP address
```

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably also need to put a `PTR` entry into your local zone for `webserver.domain.com` like `100.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR webserver.domain.com`.  The message you see indicates that your mail server (presumably running on `router.domain.com`) does not recogmise a valid `PTR` record for `webserver.domain.com`.  Though, I would expect the header to read:  `Received: from webserver.domain.com (unknown [192.168.0.100])` ...

Comment: I tried adding a PTR entry as you mentioned, however, still same thing. BTW, I'm using a sendmail emulation to talk to the mail server.

Comment: Where is the mail server installed, does the mail server run on `router.domain.com`, or is the mail server external to your network?